# Next.JS App, Static HTML starting page then start app on different page i.e "/shop"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, routes

Building a site using next.js and fontdue.js if anyone has experience & can help me create just a static html landing page I've tried putting custom route in next.config.js, but it still keeps routing to the app,

see this Github repo for original files https://github.com/fontdue/example-next

Thanks!

Tried a custom route in next.config.js cant seem to get it to work?

Comment: ++ They want then site to start on the static html then be able to link off to say /shop and the app would start

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.